# How to see the methods I can override in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I want to know how can I see the methods of the superclass directly from the class where I'm going to override the method. Is It possible? I use Eclipse and Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Goto Source -->  Override/Implement Methods**

[image]

**Here I extends Thread select the needed methods from there.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a source wizard that allows you to generate the method overrides. To select it, select <kbd>Source</kbd>/<kbd>Override/Implement methods</kbd> from either the main menu or the pop-up menu of the java editor.

The only drawback is that the output is grouped by superclass, so in case of complex inheritance hierarchy you may have to search a bit for the upper levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by following the below steps in Eclipse:

1. Right Click in your class
2. Click on 'Source'
3. Select the option 'Override/Implement methods'